# How to simulate the SCT2450KE Rohm SiC mosfet model in LTspice

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, ltspice, mosfet-driver

I am trying to simulate the SiC mosfet in ltspice of ROHM.
I am using the spice model provided by the company https://www.rohm.com/products/sic-power-devices/sic-mosfet/sct2450ke-product/tools

But still, I am not able to do the switching properly. What is the problem.
[image]

[image]

What wrong I am doing, Kindly tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check that pins 1,2,3 are what you think they are.
From the Spice listing...

```
* SCT2450KE
* SiC NMOSFET model
* 1200V 10A 450mohm
* Date: 2015/12/07
******************D G S
.SUBCKT SCT2450KE 1 2 3
```

Notice anything about the last 2 lines?

Second, what is a 1000V supply and a 10 ohm load going to do to a 10A device?

Comment: OP, this is the cause, but to avoid it for the future, just use the symbol for the `NMOS`, `CTRL+RClick` on it, change the `Prefix` from `MN` to `X`, and then change the name `NMOS` to the name of the subcircuit (here `SCT2450KE`, or whatever name there is). If you rely on auto-generated symbols, you'll end up with very ugly and confusing ones, that are likely to cause more frustration than not.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen does LTSpice translate correctly from that symbol to arbitrary pinouts in 3rd party models? (noting that the pinout in this one doesn't even agree with the device's own datasheet)

Comment: The standard pinout for transistors is DGS, CBE, etc, and the manufacturers usually obey this (I have met exceptions, but very rare). Which is not a bad thing to have to avoid chaos.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen thanks; that was the bit of the puzzle Ididn't know  or had forgotten. Good incentive for 3rd parties to follow the standard, as here.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I typically only see non-standard convention with older subcircuits, but I always check just in case.  Been burned enough times to make sure it doesn't happen again.

Comment: I got the problem solved. Yes, I have made the wrong pin connection. In the simulation, by mistake, I put the 10ohm load. It was 100ohm load, thanks for reminding me.